# BEM-style naming with specialised components

Tags: css, naming-conventions, bem

Using BEM naming conventions, how should situations where a component is a specialisation of a base component be handled? (I'm using Nicholas Gallagher's variant here).

So assuming I have a set of default styles for `table` elements and a more specialised table with a class of `DataTable`:

```
// Defaults

table {}
tr {}
th {}
td {}

// DataTable

.DataTable {}
.DataTable-header {}
.DataTable-header-row {}
.DataTable-header-cell {}
.DataTable-body {}
.DataTable-body-row {}
.DataTable-body-cell {}
```

I now have a table that is a specialisation of `DataTable`, with a variety of tweaks to cells:

```
.SpecialTable {}
.SpecialTable-header {}
.SpecialTable-header-row {}
.SpecialTable-header-cell {}
.SpecialTable-header-alphaCell {}
.SpecialTable-header-betaCell {}
.SpecialTable-header-charlieCell {}
.SpecialTable-body {}
.SpecialTable-body-row {}
.SpecialTable-body-cell {}
.SpecialTable-body-alphaCell {}
.SpecialTable-body-betaCell {}
.SpecialTable-body-charlieCell {}
```

This would then mean my SpecialTable would look like this:

```
<table class="DataTable SpecialTable">
  <theadclass="DataTable-header SpecialTable-header">
    <tr class="DataTable-header-row SpecialTable-header-row">
      <th class="DataTable-header-cell SpecialTable-header-cell SpecialTable-header-alphaCell"></th>
      <th class="DataTable-header-cell SpecialTable-header-cell SpecialTable-header-betaCell"></th>
      <th class="DataTable-header-cell SpecialTable-header-cell SpecialTable-header-betaCell"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="DataTable-body SpecialTable-body">
    <tr class="DataTable-body-row SpecialTable-body-row">
      <th class="DataTable-body-cell SpecialTable-body-cell SpecialTable-body-alphaCell"></th>
      <th class="DataTable-body-cell SpecialTable-body-cell SpecialTable-row-betaCell"></th>
      <th class="DataTable-body-cell SpecialTable-body-cell SpecialTable-row-betaCell"></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Is this the correct way to class the table?**

Answer (score 3):

Using two Modules on a same element ( `class="DataTable SpecialTable"` ) is not a good practice, instead make a modifier for the Module.

( will write it in SASS )

```
.DataTable {

    &-header {}
    &-header-row {}
    &-header-cell {}
    &-body {}
    &-body-row {}
    &-body-cell {}
}

.DataTable--special {
    .DataTable-header {}
    .DataTable-header-row {}
    .DataTable-header-cell {}
    .DataTable-header-alphaCell {}
    .DataTable-header-betaCell {}
    .DataTable-header-charlieCell {}
    .DataTable-body {}
    .DataTable-body-row {}
    .DataTable-body-cell {}
    .DataTable-body-alphaCell {}
    .DataTable-body-betaCell {}
    .DataTable-body-charlieCell {}
}
```

And then use it as `class="DataTable DataTable--special"`

Comment: Descendants `header-row`, `header-cell`, etc. must be renamed to `headerRow`, `headerCell`. See [the conventions here](https://github.com/suitcss/suit/blob/master/doc/naming-conventions.md).

Comment: that's not a BEM convention, that's a SUIT convention, it's ok in any of the two approaches,  the only thing needed to prevent is using two modules in the same element

Comment: The descendant `DataTable-header-row` (BEM syntax from SUIT CSS) is invalid. It would be equivalent to the element `data-table__header__row` (BEM syntax from Yandex), which is not valid in BEM because an element can't contain an element in the BEM tree.

Comment: ok... we're not discussing SUIT conventions here... I just recommended the modifier to be on the parent module / element

Comment: We can solve `data-table__header__row` problem this way:
`.c-dtbl { $this: &; &__hdr {} &__r {} &__hdr { #{$this}__r { // stuff } } }`